# Select values from two tables using loop

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have Two tables named

```
1.Categortable

Category

Mouse

Computer

Electronics
```

and  the second table Texttable

```
category                   Text

Mouse                     Logitech Mouse

Computer                  LG Computer

Electronics               LG Electronics
```

Here I need To select Text for each category in Categortable from Texttable

Can any one help how to loop this to get the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to do any looping here, a simple `JOIN` should work for you:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CategoryTable CT
    LEFT JOIN TextTable TT ON CT.Category = TT.Category
```

I've used a `LEFT JOIN` in case you want to return rows from your Category table which don't have a corresponding match in the Text table.

---

In case you only want the matching records, just replace the `LEFT JOIN` with an  `INNER JOIN`.

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 1):

try out this

```
Select ct.category, tt.Text from Categorytable ct
inner join Texttable tt on ct.category = tt.category
```